# MySQL SELECT syntax error that I am not able to identify

Tags: mysql

I am trying a simple query in mysql and I am getting a syntax error that I need help understanding.

```
SELECT 
    eea.*,
    ee.description,
    eect.title,
    eect.file,
    eect.location,
    eect.img_location
FROM 
    `e_exam` ee,
    `e_exam_attempt` eea,
    `e_exam_cert_template` eect
WHERE 
    eea.a_user_id = 1,
    eea.ee_id = ee.id,
    ee.eect_id = eect.id;
```

I am getting the following error:

[image: picture of error from my vm]

Basically the syntax error on line 13

```
eea.ee_id = ee.id, ee.eect_id = eect.id LIMIT 0, 25
```

Anyone have idea how I can edit this to get the -1 vote to improve?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the error as text.

Comment: **I see no ships** or any LIMIT clause

Comment: WHERE wants AND, OR etc, not commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple syntax error, your WHERE clause should not be seperated by commas. Use AND or OR etc

```
SELECT 
    eea.*, ee.description, eect.title, eect.file,
    eect.location,eect.img_location
FROM 
    `e_exam` ee,
    `e_exam_attempt` eea,
    `e_exam_cert_template` eect
WHERE 
    eea.a_user_id = 1 AND
    eea.ee_id = ee.id AND
    ee.eect_id = eect.id
LIMIT 0,25
```

> You should also learn about the JOIN syntax

```
SELECT 
    eea.*, ee.description, eect.title,eect.file,
    eect.location, eect.img_location
FROM `e_exam_attempt` eea
    JOIN `e_exam` ee ON eea.ee_id = ee.id
    JOIN `e_exam_cert_template` eect ON ee.eect_id = eect.id
WHERE 
    eea.a_user_id = 1 
LIMIT 0,25
```

Comment: Thanks, just realized the missing ANDs.